# jquery scroll to function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a button for traversing down my page by using .parent, .next, and .find and this is getting an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

html:

```
<div id="mainbody">
    <div class="hero-unit">
        <div class="next"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="index-block">
        <div class="next"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="index-block">
        <div class="next"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="index-block">
        <div class="next"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
/********************************
/ SCROLL TO NEXT
/*******************************/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.next').on("click", function() {
            var next;
            next = $('#mainbody').parent().next().find(".index-block");
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: next.offset().top + 65}, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Reproduce this in JSFiddle. Also, console.log(next) variable to see what happens to it while you click.

Comment: Please post the complete html (it's missing element with .index-block class) or put in a jsFiddle.
And you have some elements with same id (next), which can give some problems.

Comment: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93gcn633/

Comment: updated fiddle with id changed to class
http://jsfiddle.net/93gcn633/1/

Comment: @RicardoPontual I'm not sure what you mean by "complete" the html. I did change the ids to classes for "next", but the hero unit is not an index-block. the idea is to have the script find the next of mainbody so even in an a different element it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some changes in your code

HTML

```
<div id="mainbody">
    <div class="index-block hero-unit">
        <div class="next"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="index-block">
        <div class="next"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="index-block">
        <div class="next"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="index-block">
        <div class="next"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hero-unit, .index-block {
    background-color: #efefef;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.next {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;    
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.next').on("click", function() {
        if($(this).parent().next(".index-block").offset() != undefined){
            var next = $(this).parent().next(".index-block").offset();
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: next.top}, 1000);
        }   
    });
});
```